# I want to populate value in Dataframe based on matching values in other Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement

I am editing the question. I dont want to use groupby to use group values.
I would appreciate if someone could help with just the query to transform data in the following way:

I have one dataframe given as follows:

```
df1:

col1    col2
------------
VG       12
G        11
A        10
P        06
VP       0
```

I want the new dataframe such as:

```
df2:

VG    G   A   P   VP
---------------------
12    11  10   06  0
```

I tried achieving this using if condition and I got following error:
Code:

```
 if df1.Score=='VG':
    df2['VG']=df1.loc[df1['col1'] == 'VG', 'col2']

 The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), 
 a.item(), a.any() or a.all()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`agg` and `transform` would work :)

```
df.groupby('col1').agg(list).col2.transform(pd.Series).T.fillna(0)

    A   G   P       VG          VP
0   10.0    11.0    6.0 12.0    0.0
1   50.0    0.0     0.0 53.0    0.0
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have to populate to a different dataframe for the operation.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @ user2285236 for improve answer:

```
s = df1.groupby('col1').cumcount()

df = (df1.set_index(['col1', s])['col2']
         .unstack(level=0, fill_value=0)
         .rename_axis(None, 1))
print (df)
    A   G  P  VG  VP
0  10  11  6  12   0
1  50   0  0  53   0
```

Explanation:

1. Create `MultiIndex` by [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) by first column with `Series` created by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for count values per groups for new index
2. Reshape by [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html)
3. Data cleaning by [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html)

Comment: I think 'VG' was just an example there. You can generalize this with cumcount instead ( `s = df1.groupby('col1').cumcount()`).

Answer (score 0):

Here's the long way, if all else fails:

```
s = [pd.Series(g.loc[g['col2'] != 0, 'col2'].values, name=k) \
     for k, g in df.groupby('col1')]

res = pd.concat(s, axis=1, ignore_index=False).fillna(0)

print(res)

    A     G    P  VG   VP
0  10  11.0  6.0  12  0.0
1  50   0.0  0.0  53  0.0
```